# I got a crack on background after rendering

Tags: rendering, error

[image]

[image]

After rendering my animation, these cracks appear on my background images.

[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KK8nH.png)

[image]

These are my settings. I'm using denoise.
please help me

here is my blender file

https://blend-exchange.com/b/qbZ4yANq

The crack appears randomly.
when I render the file at first, it does appears at 17th frame.
But at the second time, the crack does not appears at all.

Comment: Hi, and welcome. Is your background an image? Can you show us how that works?

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: here is my blender file

https://blend-exchange.com/b/qbZ4yANq

The crack appears randomly. when I render the file at first, it does appears at 17th frame. But at the second time, the crack does not appears at all.